# Sharing data between an adapter-recyclerview and another class

Tags: java, android

I want to send in a variable the position of a click on an Item in a other activity. I show you my work that does not work. The application quits when I press an item.

**MyViewHolder in my adapter:**

```
public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get position
            int poss = getAdapterPosition();

            // sharing position
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", poss );
            mContext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    });
```

**And my Activity for recept:**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


private TextView textTest;
int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    String position = String.valueOf(id);

    textTest = findViewById(R.id.text_test);

    textTest.setText(position);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textTest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        textTest = findViewById(R.id.text_test);
        int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");
        String position = String.valueOf(id);
        textTest.setText(position);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this  line of code `int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");` from outside of the onCreate() method & put this code inside of your onCreate Method in Main2Activity

```
        textTest = findViewById(R.id.text_test);
        int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");
        String position = String.valueOf(id);
        textTest.setText(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Interface class

```
Public interface OnPostionClick{
Public void yourmethod(int pos)
}
```

Place interface method on Adapter viewHolder `onClick` method

```
If(context instanceof OnPostionClick){
((OnPostionClick) context).yourmethod(poss);
}
```

implement `OnPostionClick` interface on **Second Activity** and override `yourmethod`